# Determine when at least one checkbox is checked in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, dom

I'm trying to determine when at least one checkbox is checked in React.

I have a Checkbox component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as DOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }

    render() {
      return(
        <div>
        <label>
        <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      name={this.props.value} 
      value={this.props.value} 
      onClick={this.props.function}
      />
    <span>
      <span>
        {this.props.title}
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
  </div>
      );
    }
}

Checkbox.PropTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  function: PropTypes.func,
}

export default NewsletterCheckbox;
```

It is imported and used in a parent component:

```
  checkFields() {
    // check if other fields are not empty and valid
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  isCheckboxChecked(event) {
    // determine if at least one checkbox is checked, and if so
    // update state
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    const checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);
    if (checkedOne) {
      this.setState({ checkboxValid: true }, this.checkFields);
    } else {
      this.setState({ checkboxValid: false }, this.checkFields);
    }
  }     
  const newsletterArray = NewsletterData.map((obj) => (
    <div key={obj.value}>
      <div>
      <Checkbox
        value={obj.value}
        title={obj.title}
        function={this.isCheckboxChecked}
        />
      </div>
      <p>
          {obj.body}
          <br />
        <a onClick={(e) =>  {this.handleModal(e) }} data-iframe={obj.link}>
            See Preview
          </a>
        </p>
    </div>
  ));
```

The issue I'm running in to is that the function that runs when any of the checkboxes are checked, `isCheckboxChecked()`, once one field has been checked, if I uncheck that field (or check a bunch, and then uncheck them all), it never comes back as false.

Is there a better way of checking if at least one checkbox is checked in React without querying the DOM (which doesn't seem to work correctly with React rendered checkboxes)?

Comment: Don't query the DOM. Keep an array in the parent's `state` to store the state of your checkboxes. That state is passed down to each Checkbox, and the function you pass down will change the parent's state array. This way you can read the state of the checkboxes at any time.

Comment: You should probably implement `onChange` and keep the state of the checkbox in the parent component. This way you'll be able to check whether the selected ones meet you criteria. In React you should almost never resort to querying the DOM, and if had to, you would use `ref` not direct DOM queries.

Comment: Here's how I do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-banach-rm7qd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a counter of the checked checkbox

```js
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name={this.props.value} 
    value={this.props.value} 
    onChange={this.props.onChange} />
```

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {checkCount: 0}
}

<Checkbox
   value={obj.value}
   title={obj.title}
   onChange={(e) => {
     if (e.target.checked)
       this.setState((prevState) => ({checkCount: prevState.checkCount + 1, checkboxValid: true}))
     else {
       this.setState((prevState) => ({checkCount: prevState.checkCount - 1}), () => {
         if (this.state.checkCount === 0)
           this.setState({checkboxValid: false})
       })
     }
   }} />
```

We are setting the checkCount to +1 or -1 if the user checks or unchecks the checkbox. If he unchecks it, after updating the checkCount, we need to verify `this.state.checkCount === 0` in order to set the `checkboxValid` state to false if the condition is valid.

Comment: The first condtion on the onChange handler throws an error. I'm assuming it needs to be wrapped in the arrow func like the one in the else condition? Either way, neither of these seem to update the state of either values (checkCount or checkboxValid).

Comment: I edited the answer (forgot some `()` : `{checkCount: prevState.checkCount - 1}` => `({checkCount: prevState.checkCount - 1})`). You can check the live version here : https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-aryabhata-ub2qn